# WhatsApp chat-api registration process error

Tags: php, whatsapp

I am using WhatsApp Chat-API.
For registration process I follow the documentation as provided at 
[Documentation](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API/wiki/WhatsAPI-Documentation).

So for registration process I use the below code

```
$username = "mynumber";
$debug = true;
$r = new Registration($username, $debug);
$r->codeRequest('sms');
```

Now till here I get the msg for verification but the problem is how I can use code received on phone as next line of code is as given below

```
$code = '123456';// this is hard coded in documentation how i can use my verification code which i received on my phone
$r->codeRegister($code);
```

So after getting verification code how I use the above code to get login password?

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to comment out `$r->codeRegister($code)` during the first run. Then I wait for WhatsApp to send the code. When I get the code on my phone, I comment out `$r->codeRequest('sms') and uncomment`$r->codeRegister($code)`; replacing`$code` with the code the WhatsApp API sent.

It's a hackneyed way of doing this but it works.

Ideally, you should get `$code` from STDIN which waits for the user to type it in.